# How to COPY, CLONE, MIMIC, SPLIT win forms control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use CUSTOM grid cell as a template for a CUSTOM grid .

The grid is made out of panels .

A panel has an INNER control associated with it .

When two different panels are assigned the same INNER CONTROL CELL template, one hides the other .

How do I COPY, CLONE, MIMIC, SPLIT the CELL template into a new completelly separate instance of an object ?

I tried looking up online, but nothing useful so far .

There was something related to (CustomControl)(CustomControl as Array).Clone() but it did not work .

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class GCell
{
    public GCell(GCell template)
    {
        SetForeStyle(template.SelectedForeColor, template.DeselectedForeColor);

        SetBackStyle(template.SelectedBackColor, template.DeselectedBackColor);

        SetBorderStyle(template.SelectedBorderColor, template.DeselectedBorderColor);

        SetBorderWidthStyle(template.SelectedBorderWidth, template.DeselectedBorderWidth);

        ExposeOrigin();

        CentralOrder();

        return;
    }
}
```

Did not exactly solve the concrete issue but it did solve my issue